# Nuxt child routes re-render whole page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use child routes to keep some data active on the page while changing some content.

I've setup a simple example at https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-shape-22bom

click on "cat" and then increase the counter a few times. Then click on dog and the counter is reset. But I need the counter to retain its count.

Am I just fundamentally misunderstanding what `<nuxt-child>` is supposed to do?

Comment: You use `asyncData` and set the counter value to `0` each time you do change any route, this is why the counter value is not preserved. You may use keep-alive if the state is **inside** of component's state, like here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components You do have it in the upper scope here.

Comment: @kissu Using `asyncData` is not actually the cause of the problem. It's because the counter lives in the page itself, and each page (`/cat` and `/dog`) is a unique instance with its own counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each page (`/cat` and `/dog`) has its own instance of the counter, so they're independent from each other. To keep the counter active, you could move it into the layout.

For example, you could move the counter into its own component (e.g. `ButtonCounter.vue`) and use it in the layout:

```html
// components/ButtonCounter.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button @click="counter++">increase</button>
      <p>button clicked {{ counter }} times</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 0,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
// layout/default.vue
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <ul style="padding: 20px; border: 1px solid black">
      <li><nuxt-link to="/cat">cat</nuxt-link></li>
      <li><nuxt-link to="/dog">dog</nuxt-link></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
      <ButtonCounter />
      <Nuxt />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-reuse-layout-component?file=layouts%2Fdefault.vue)

Comment: yeah. In my real project, I have access to a store and the data is not a counter, but a giant JSON object, so maybe I'll try it out there. Do you know the performance impacts of using `keep-alive`? its actually a pretty big app, and I don't really need any other components to keep alive.

Comment: @solidau don't use `keep-alive` on it so. Your issue is not related to it anyway.

Comment: Technically, `keep-alive` does have filters so that only specific components are kept alive, but I don't think `keep-alive` is the right solution here.

Comment: It all depends on how you want to keep it persisted too: localStorage, use `v-show`, vuex or with a `keep-alive` (even if I'm not sure how it behaves with a dynamic route). Lot of possibilities but it depends also a lot of your app.

Comment: @kissu yeah, I'm starting to realize that... I think I will need to come up with a more complete example to better illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @tony19 I went ahead and marked this as answer since it solves the problem I stated in the question, but I might try coming up with a more complete example later on. If so I'll link it here - thanks for your efforts!